# Potential flow involving a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, potential-flow

I am currently working on a problem involving a sphere being dragged through a fluid at constant velocity.

Working in the rest frame of the sphere I'm told the potential is of the form:
$$\frac{k\cos(\theta)}{r^2}$$ (in spherical polar coordinates).

Upon differentiating this it appears as though there is a radial component of the velocity on the surface of the sphere itself:

$$V(r,θ) = \frac{-2k \cos(\theta)}{r^3}$$

Is this potential incorrect, and in general what boundary conditions must apply for such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working in a frame of reference where the far-field fluid is static and the sphere is moving, so yes there will be a radial velocity on the sphere's surface.

If the sphere has radius $R$:

- $\theta=0$ (back of the sphere): $V=-2k/R^3$, so the velocity of the sphere
- $\theta=\pi/2$ (side of the sphere): $V=0$
- $\theta=\pi$ (front of the sphere): $V=2k/R^3$, velocity of the sphere but now the radial direction is pointing the other way so the sign is opposite.

In a frame of reference where the sphere is stationary, then you'd get that there's zero radial velocity on the sphere's surface.

In general, the condition is that there is zero *relative* normal velocity through a solid surface.